# How to limit the content length of the text editor

Tags: editor, text-editor, vue-cli, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and vue3-editor(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-editor)
and I think I should limit the length of content so what i did is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME0xy.jpg)image

```
/**What i did */
      if (this.quill.getLength() > 50) {
        this.quill.deleteText(50, this.quill.getLength());
      }
/*/
```

I added this block of code at vue3-editor.common.js , vue3-editor.umd.js

I don't even know why the same code is in two files.

How can I limit the length, or is there another simple basic editor for vue3?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change the files `vue3-editor.common.js` or `vue3-editor.umd.js` as those files are distribution of `vue3-editor` and will be overwritten every time you update this dependency (generally **do not change anything in `node_modules` directly** !)

The good thing is you don't need to as the `vue3-editor` component (which is using [Quill.js](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) inside) is routing the `text-change` event from Quill to you (see [examples](https://www.vue2editor.com/examples/#listening-for-events))

Template:

```html
<vue-editor ref="editor" v-model="content" @text-change="onTextChange" />
```

Script

```js
data() {
  return {
    content: '',
    limit: 50
  }
},
methods: {
  onTextChange() {
    const quill = this.$refs.editor.quill
    const len = quill.getLength()
    if (len > this.limit) {
      quill.deleteText(this.limit, len);
    }
  }
}
```

Although when reading the [issue](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/688) I do not think this is perfect solution for what you want...